# Kile inverse search fails with Texlive 2011

Tags: texlive, kile, forward-inverse-search

I am using Scientific Linux 6.1. When I installed Kile it came with Texlive 2007 so I installed Texlive 2011 and made necessary changes to make Kile use  Texlive 2011.
The problem is , am unable to get pdf inverse search working. I was an Ubuntu user before and I have used kile + texlive 2009 with pdf inverse search  for some years now.
 1. I have configured things as before (modern configuration, synctex=1, set kile as default in okular etc)
2. the synctex.gz file is created, but when I shift+click on pdf file, nothing happens. I dont see any error/output messages either.

Please help.

Comment: If the name of the `.tex` file has an accented character like â or á, etc, the inverse search may not work. The same happens if the path to your file has some such char.